# What is the difference in calling Future and Future.microtask in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

From the documentation for the [`Future.microtask` constructor](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-async/Future/Future.microtask.html), it says:

```
   * Creates a future containing the result of calling [computation]
   * asynchronously with [scheduleMicrotask].
```

and the documentation for the [regular `Future` constructor](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-async/Future/Future.html) states:

```
   * Creates a future containing the result of calling [computation]
   * asynchronously with [Timer.run].
```

I am wondering, what kind of implications do they have on coding, and when should we use one or another?

Comment: see [The Event Loop and Dart](https://dart.cn/articles/archive/event-loop)

Comment: @pskink That link will likely break in the future. I included an archive link in my answer that should not break.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot yep, i dont know why they removed it from english version (i know it may be outdated but still there is a lot outdated stuff on english version)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

All microtasks are executed before any other `Future`s/`Timer`s.

This means that you will want to schedule a microtask when you want to complete a small computation asynchronously as soon as possible.

```dart
void main() {
  Future(() => print('future 1'));
  Future(() => print('future 2'));
  // Microtasks will be executed before futures.
  Future.microtask(() => print('microtask 1'));
  Future.microtask(() => print('microtask 2'));
}
```

You can [run this example on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=dd141f641713c074baacba9e45115c59).

The event loop will simply pick up all microtasks in a FIFO fashion before other futures. A microtask queue is created when you schedule microtasks and that queue is executed before other futures (event queue).

---

There is an outdated archived article for [*The Event Loop and Dart*](https://web.archive.org/web/20170704074724/https://webdev.dartlang.org/articles/performance/event-loop), which covers the **event queue** and **microtask queue** [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170704074724/https://webdev.dartlang.org/articles/performance/event-loop#darts-event-loop-and-queues).

You can also learn more about microtasks with this [helpful resource](https://youtu.be/pHpvfaanrbw).

Comment: If you want to read the latest article about event loops & isolates from the dart team, it is here,  [Dart asynchronous programming: Isolates and event loops](https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-asynchronous-programming-isolates-and-event-loops-bffc3e296a6a)

Comment: The dart team also created a video about Isolates & event loops, here is the link [Isolates and Event Loops - Flutter in Focus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vl_AaCgudcY)

Answer (score 50):

Here is a simple example of how code would run in sequence in terms of how `Future`s are executed. In the example below, the resulting print statements wouldn't be in alphabetical order.

```dart
void main() async{
  print("A");
  await Future((){
    print("B");
    Future(()=>print("C"));
    Future.microtask(()=>print("D"));
    Future(()=>print("E"));
    print("F");
  });
  print("G");
}
```

The resulting print statements would end up in the order shown below. Notice how B, F, and G gets printed first, then C, then E. This is because B,F, and G are synchronous. D then gets called before C and E because of it being a microtask.

[image]